# Discover Already known domains to netflix eureka

Tags: netflix-eureka, service-discovery, autodiscovery

I already have an old reverse proxy system working for my project.
There we have approx. 250 client domain with details like **Domain port and context root present in DB**.

Now I am trying to move these setup to Netflix eureka.

Is there a way to auto register these domain from DB to Netflix eureka rather then doing a discovery